# Why are Scala "for loop comprehensions" so very slow compared to FOR loops?

Tags: performance, scala, for-loop

It has been said that Scala For comprehensions are actually quite slow. The reason I was given was that due to a Java limitation, for comprehensions (such as "reduce", used below) need to generate a temporary object with each iteration in order to call the function passed in.

IS...THIS...TRUE? The tests below seem to bear this out, but I do not completely understand why this is the case.

This might make sense for "lambdas" or anonymous functions, but not for non-anonymous functions.

In my test, I ran for loops against list.reduce (see code below), and found them to be over twice as fast, even when each iteration called the exact same function that was passed to reduce!

I find this amazingly counter-intuitive (once would think that the Scala library would've been carefully created to be as optimal as possible).

In a test I put together, I ran the same loop (sum up the numbers 1 to a million, irrespective of overflow) five different ways:

1. for loop over the array of values
2. for loop, but calling a function instead of inline arithmetic
3. for loop, creating an object that contains an addition function
4. list.reduce, passing i an anonymous function
5. list.reduce, passing in an object member function

Results were as follows:
test: min/max/average (milliseconds)

```
1. 27/157/64.78
2. 27/192/65.77 <--- note the similarity between tests 1,2 and 4,5
3. 139/313/202.58
4. 63/342/150.18
5. 63/341/149.99
```

As can be seen, the "for comprehension" versions are on the order of "for with new for each instance", implying that a "new" may in fact be performed for both the anonymous and non-anonymous function versions.

Methodology: code below (test call removed) was compiled into a single .jar file to ensure all versions ran the same library code. Each test in each iteration was called in a new JVM (i.e. scala -cp ... for each test) in order to remove heap size issues.

```
class t(val i: Int) {
    def summit(j: Int) = j + i
}

object bar {
    val biglist:List[Int]  =  (1 to 1000000).toList

    def summit(i: Int, j:Int) = i+j

    // Simple for loop
    def forloop:  Int = {
        var result: Int = 0
        for(i <- biglist) {
            result += i
        }
        result
    }

    // For loop with a function instead of inline math
    def forloop2:  Int = {
        var result: Int = 0
        for(i <- biglist) {
            result = summit(result,i)
        }
        result
    }

    // for loop with a generated object PER iteration
    def forloop3: Int = {
        var result: Int = 0
        for(i <- biglist) {
            val t = new t(result)
            result = t.summit(i)
        }
        result
    }

    // list.reduce with an anonymous function passed in
    def anonymousfunc: Int = {
        biglist.reduce((i,j) => {i+j})
    }

    // list.reduce with a named function
    def realfunc: Int = {
        biglist.reduce(summit)
    }

    // test calling code excised for brevity. One example given:
    args(0) match {
        case "1" => {
                    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    forloop
                    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    println("for="+(end - start))
                    }
         ...
}
```

Comment: `.reduce` has nothing to do with "for comprehensions"

Comment: As a side note, there is scala compiler plugin that aims to remove this overhead for common cases: https://code.google.com/p/scalacl/wiki/ScalaCLPlugin. I have not tried it myself though.

Comment: In fact, your first 3 tests are using for-comprehensions, and you're comparing timing of those with `reduce`..

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles :: ScalaCL aims (back to Scala 2.9) to produce code for OpenCL, i.e: for running on GPUs. In particular, you can also tell it to do its job, but generate code for the CPU (not the GPU). It works pretty well but, unfortunately, it is heavily based on macros, which is moving target in Scala, changing from version to version. ScalaCL is not available in recent versions of Scala.

Comment: Well, when I wrote that comment scala 2.10 had just been released. And scalaCL was explicitely advertised as a way to speed up loops (in addition to its OpenCL capabilities). I quote: "It also optimizes general Scala loops (on arrays, lists and inline ranges) often by a big margin so you'll want to use it even if you don't care about OpenCL". As a side note, it is/was a compiler plugin, not a set of macros (though I guess it's a moot point as it makes if more dependent on implementation details and thus even less dependable).

Answer (score 16):

What you were told was true about "for comprehensions", but the problem with your question is that you've mixed up "for comprehensions" with "anonymous functions".

"For comprehension" in Scala is a syntactic sugar for a series of `.flatMap`, `.map` and `.filter` applications. Since you are testing reduction algorithms and since it's impossible to implement a reduction algorithm using those three functions, your test cases are incorrect.

Here's an example of a "for comprehension":

```
val listOfLists = List(List(1,2), List(3,4), List(5))
val result = 
  for {
    itemOfListOfLists <- listOfLists
    itemOfItemOfListOfLists <- itemOfListOfLists
  }
  yield (itemOfItemOfListOfLists + 1)
assert( result == List(2,3,4,5,6) )
```

The compiler desugars the Comprehension part to the following:

```
val result =
  listOfLists.flatMap(
    itemOfListOfLists => itemOfListOfLists.map(
      itemOfItemOfListOfLists => itemOfItemOfListOfLists + 1
    )
  )
```

Then it desugars the Anonymous Function syntax:

```
val result =
  listOfLists.flatMap(
    new Function1[List[Int], List[Int]] {
      override def apply(itemOfListOfLists: List[Int]): List[Int] =
        itemOfListOfLists.map(
          new Function1[Int, Int] {
            override def apply(itemOfItemOfListOfLists: Int): Int =
              itemOfItemOfListOfLists + 1
          }
        )
    }
  )
```

From the desugarred code it's now evident that the `Function1[Int, Int]` class gets instantiated every time the `apply(itemOfListOfLists: List[Int]): List[Int]` method gets called. That happens for every entry of `listOfLists`. So the more complex your comprehension is the more instantiations of the `Function` objects you get.